# Move image bottom to top in android

Tags: android, image, android-animation

Hi i am developing one application using image ,my requirement is whenever i clicked button the image have to move  bottom to top and whenever i clicked stop button the image have to stop it position.but i am getting only either image move bottom or top

my code is

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/rl_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/graphics"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
 <Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:text="START"/>
 <Button  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"/>

 </LinearLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); 
           rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
            if (isBottom) {
                SlideToAbove();

                isBottom = false;
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);

            }else {
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
                rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
                SlideToDown();
                isBottom = true;
            }  

        }
    });

}

public void SlideToAbove() {
    final Animation slide ;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

           rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
             lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

public void SlideToDown() {
  final  Animation slide ;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(500);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

           rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
slide.setFillAfter(true);
```

This causes the image to jump to the end when you stop the animation.

You'll have to add the code to set the image position after stopping it.

Comment: did you also add the code to set the image position? see my answer

Comment: the code to set the position of the view in onAnimationEnd. I cant write it in a textbox, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at [Object Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) which is more powerfull than regular ones.

And if your application's api level is less than 9 you can refer [this library](http://nineoldandroids.com/) to still be able to use those methods. This library has also some examples about how to manage what you want to.